# How to disable Nextjs from pre-rendering a page?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, rendering, client-side

How can I truly CSR (client-side render) some pages in my NextJs application?

The documentation says that the presence of either `getServerSideProps` or `getStaticSiteProps` in a page would make it pre-render on the server per request or at build time respectively.

Yet again, with the advent of [automatic static optimisation](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/automatic-static-optimization) NextJs determines automatically whether or not to pre-render a statically in the absence of `getServerSideProps` or `getInitialProps` — If I understand this statement currently, it means that *all pages that don't export the aforementioned server-side functions, will be be statically generated on the server*

So my question now is how do I truly render on client side only for pages like dashboard, without having nextjs automatically pre-render due to automatic static optimization?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can disable SSR for a specific component while exporting it.

```js
const NoSSRYourComponent = () => {
    return (
        // ... NoSSRYourComponent code
    )
}

// export it with SSR disabled
const YourComponent = dynamic(() => Promise.resolve(NoSSRYourComponent), {
  ssr: false,
})

export default YourComponent
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply Shubham, but can you please provide a little more context to this answer or better yet a reference to a doc? Thanks

Comment: So the main motto behind disabling `ssr` is to dynamically load a component on the client side. This is useful if a component relies on browser APIs like `window` or you want to render it client side specifically. [refer docs for more info](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import#with-no-ssr)

Comment: Either you can import it using `dynamic` but exporting it dynamically will allow you to directly use that component without disabling `ssr` every time you import.

Comment: Ahh yes! After looking at the doc, I am convinced that this is the solution for my problem. Thanks a lot Shubham!

Comment: Thank you! you finally solved my problem with export errors